# Truffle test : Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: mocha.js, assert, solidity, truffle

I have seen this error many times. nothing online could help resolve it

I use multiple times in a row the same function startProposalRegistration to test different scenario with or without restriction.

I am testing that my modifier is working as expected by throwing if account is not owner (onlyOwner).

the transaction reverts but I do not get much explanation as to why the transaction reverts other than it is executed several times

```
  context("startProposalRegistration", () => {
    it("should be status == ProposalsRegistrationStarted", async () => {
      await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: owner })
      const status = await votingInstance.status.call()
      assert.equal(status.toNumber(), 1)
    })
    // it("should not be able to startProposalRegistration as non owner", async () => {
    //   assert.equal(await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: account2 }), false);

    // })
  })

  context("add/delete proposal", () => {
    it("should be able to add proposal if status == ProposalsRegistrationStarted", async () => {
      await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: owner })
      assert.ok(await votingInstance.addProposal("Some proposal", { from: whitelisted }))
    })
    // it("should not be able to add proposal if status != ProposalsRegistrationStarted", async () => {
    //   await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: account2 })

    // })
  })
```

**test/Voting.js** (full source code)

```
const { assert } = require("chai");
const should = require("chai").should();
const Voting = artifacts.require("Voting");

contract("Voting", accounts => {
  let [account1, account2] = accounts;
  let [, , address3, address4] = accounts;
  let owner = account1;
  let whitelisted = address4;
  let votingInstance;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    votingInstance = await Voting.deployed();
    await votingInstance.addVoter(whitelisted, { from: owner }); //adding to whitelist
  });

  it("should deploy", async () => {
    should.exist(votingInstance.address)
  });

  it("should be status == RegisteringVoters", async () => {
    const status = await votingInstance.status.call()
    assert.equal(status.toNumber(), 0)
  })

  context("add/delete Voter", () => {
    it("should be able to add voter as a owner", async () => {
      await votingInstance.addVoter(address3, { from: owner })
      const voter = await votingInstance.whiteList.call(address3);
      assert(voter);
    })
    it("should not be able to add voter as a non owner", async () => {
      try {
        await votingInstance.addVoter(address4, { from: account2 })
        assert(false);
      } catch (err) {
        should.exist(err);
      }
    })
    it("should be able to delete voter as a owner", async () => {
      await votingInstance.deleteVoter(address3, { from: owner })
      const voter = await votingInstance.whiteList.call(address3);
      should.not.exist(voter.address);
    })
    it("should not be able to delete voter as non owner", async () => {
      try {
        await votingInstance.deleteVoter(address3, { from: account2 })
        assert(false);
      } catch (err) {
        should.exist(err);
      }
    })
  })

  context("startProposalRegistration", () => {
    it("should be status == ProposalsRegistrationStarted", async () => {
      await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: owner })
      const status = await votingInstance.status.call()
      assert.equal(status.toNumber(), 1)
    })
    // it("should not be able to startProposalRegistration as non owner", async () => {
    //   assert.equal(await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: account2 }), false);

    // })
  })

  context("add/delete proposal", () => {
    it("should be able to add proposal if status == ProposalsRegistrationStarted", async () => {
      await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: owner })
      assert.ok(await votingInstance.addProposal("Some proposal", { from: whitelisted }))
    })
    // it("should not be able to add proposal if status != ProposalsRegistrationStarted", async () => {
    //   await votingInstance.startProposalRegistration({ from: account2 })

    // })
  })

})
```

and the contract
**contracts/Voting.sol**

the function I have been having issues with :

```
function startProposalRegistration() public onlyOwner   {
        status = WorkflowStatus.ProposalsRegistrationStarted;
        emit ProposalsRegistrationStarted();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42995/how-to-send-ether-to-a-contract-in-truffle-test I have managed to look up. It is because of contract function requiring ether to be sent, especially marked 'payable'

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.